# For a normal Subgroup $N$ of $G$, is there an Isomorphism from $G$ to $N\times (G/N)$?

Tags: group-theory

For a normal Subgroup $N$ of $G$, is there an Isomorphism from $G$ to $N\times (G/N)$ (the Product with the Quotient)?

[What I thought about: The number of elements is the same, so one could establish a bijective Map. But it is difficult for me to come up with a Homomorphism. One could map $g$ to $(n,gN)$ in $N\times (G/N)$ and if $g\in N$, one could choose $n=g$, otherwise I thought about taking one representative from each coset $g_1N, g_2N, \cdots, g_nN$ and define the map as $\varphi(g\in g_iN):=(g_i^{-1}g,g_iN)$. But then
$\phi(g\in g_iN)\phi(g'\in g_jN)=(g_i^{-1}g,g_iN)(g_j^{-1}g',g_jN)=(g_i^{-1}gg_j^{-1}g',g_ig_jN)$
which does not seem to be a Homomorphism.]

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: Notable fact: the statement $N$ is normal is equivalent to the statement that
$$
0 \to N \to G \to G/N \to 0
$$
is a (short) exact sequence.  The desired conclusion of $G \cong N \times G/N$ is equivalent to saying that the above is a *split (short) exact sequence*.

Comment: Also notable: your statement will be true if and only if there exists a homomorphism $\phi:G/N \to G$ such that $$\pi \circ \phi = \mathsf{id}_{G/N}$$ (here, $\pi$ is the canonical quotient map).

Comment: Nice, thanks, can you give also a reference for the two comments?
I am new to Group Theory and would like to understand them better.

Comment: Dummit and Foote, Section 10.5, Proposition 25.  Dummit and Foote is a good reference to have on hand anyhow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, take $G=Z$ and $N=2Z$. $Z$ is not isomorphic to $2Z\times Z/(2Z)$ since it does not have element of order 2.

If you assume $G$ is finite, let $G=S_n, n>5$ the symmetric group, and $A_n\subset S_n$ the alternating subgroup the kernel of the signature. $S_n/A_n=S_2$, but $S_n$ is not isomorphic to $A_n\times S_2$, since $A_n$ is the only normal proper subgroup of $S_n$.

http://planetmath.org/normalsubgroupsofthesymmetricgroups

Comment: Thanks, good point, do you mean $2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/(2\mathbb{Z}$)?
What about finite Groups?

Comment: Thank you. Could you still please rewrite $2Z\times Z/2$ to $2Z\times Z/(2Z)$. Thanks. Just for others that may read the answer = )

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of a small finite group, for which you can check exhaustively that no isomorphism exists:

Take $G:=\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$ and $N:=2\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$ its only nontrivial subgroup. Then $G/N\cong\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$, but there is no isomorphism
$$G\ \stackrel{\sim}{\longrightarrow}\ N\times(G/N),$$
because there is no element of order $4$ on the right.

Answer (score 2):

No. This is not true at all. Note that if what you think were true every solvable group would be abelian.

For a specific example take $S_3$ and the subgroup $A_3$ which is cyclic of order $3$. The quotient is cyclic of order $2$. So the product is abelian, in fact cyclic of order $6$. But $S_3$ is non-abelian.

It is not true for commutative groups either. It even does not  work with a group of smallest cardinality that has non-trivial subgroups: the cyclic group of order $4$ has a subgroup of order $2$, the quotient is also of order $2$, so the product is the Klein four group, not the cyclic group of order $4$.

There are some classes of groups where what you ask for is true (e.g., elementary abelian groups, divisible abelian groups), but in general it's not true at all.

Comment: Thanks for adding the cases when the statement is true!